# Android Studio App Keeps on Crashing Without any Errors

Tags: java, android

I have made an Android Studio app that plays an mp3 file when you click a button. Suddenly it started crashing. I have checked the code myself and I cannot spot any errors. I tried reinstalling the emulator too and using a physical android device to connect, but still the same issue happens. Here is the java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button yes;
    private Button no;
    private ImageButton iwant;
    private ImageButton food;
    private ImageButton restroom;
    private ImageButton water;
    private ImageButton playground;
    private ImageButton rice;
    private ImageButton school;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        yes = findViewById(R.id.yes);
        no = findViewById(R.id.no);
        iwant = findViewById(R.id.iwant);
        food = findViewById(R.id.food);
        restroom = findViewById(R.id.restroom);
        water = findViewById(R.id.water);
        playground = findViewById(R.id.playground);
        rice = findViewById(R.id.rice);
        school = findViewById(R.id.school);

        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.yes);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.no);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer3 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.iwant);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer4 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.food);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer5 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.restroom);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer6 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.water);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer7 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.playground);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer8 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.rice);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer9 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.school);

        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer2.start();
            }
        });
        iwant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer3.start();
            }
        });
        food.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer4.start();
            }
        });
        restroom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer5.start();
            }
        });
        water.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer6.start();
            }
        });
        playground.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer7.start();
            }
        });
        rice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer8.start();
            }
        });
        school.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer9.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the crash is in os level therefore you can't easily catch it. you should inspect all app, os logs, in terminal.

Comment: Whenever you lauch the app, start the logcat of the android studio. When ever app will crash, it will stop printing. That might be able to give us some clues. Plus I think there are too many objects of media player starting on single click. Try with starting one object ,two objects etc. You will likely find the cause.